# Input aaData of datatable outside of the datatable

Tags: javascript

first of all take my apologies I am new in programming world, I am stack with one of my personal project I need help from you guys first I will share the code of my project

PHP Laravel Code:

```
class studentsController extends Controller
{
     public function index(){
         return view('index');
     }

     // Fetch records
     public function getstudents(Request $request){

        ## Read value
        $draw = $request->get('draw');
        $start = $request->get("start");
        $rowperpage = $request->get("length"); // Rows display per page

        $columnIndex_arr = $request->get('order');
        $columnName_arr = $request->get('columns');
        $order_arr = $request->get('order');
        $search_arr = $request->get('search');

        $columnIndex = $columnIndex_arr[0]['column']; // Column index
        $columnName = $columnName_arr[$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
        $columnSortOrder = $order_arr[0]['dir']; // asc or desc
        $searchValue = $search_arr['value']; // Search value

        // Total records
        $totalRecords = students::select('count(*) as allcount')->count();
        $totalRecordswithFilter = students::select('count(*) as allcount')->where('name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')->count();

        $totalFemaleStudent = students::where('gender', 1)->('date_time', 'LIKE', '%'.$CurrentDate.'%')->count('gender');
        $totalMaleStudent = students::where('gender', 2)->('date_time', 'LIKE', '%'.$CurrentDate.'%')->count('gender');

        // Fetch records
        $records = students::orderBy($columnName, $columnSortOrder)
               ->where('students.name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
              ->select('students.*')
              ->skip($start)
              ->take($rowperpage)
              ->get();

        $data_arr = array();

        foreach($records as $record){
           $id = $record->id;
           $username = $record->username;
           $name = $record->name;
           $email = $record->email;

           $data_arr[] = array(
               "id" => $id,
               "username" => $username,
               "name" => $name,
               "email" => $email,
               "totalMaleStudent" => $totalMaleStudent,
               "totalFemaleStudent" => $totalFemaleStudent
           );
        }

        $response = array(
           "draw" => intval($draw),
           "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
           "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordswithFilter,
           "aaData" => $data_arr
        );

        return response()->json($response); 
     }
}
```

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Datatables AJAX pagination with Search and Sort in Laravel 10</title>

     <!-- Meta -->
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <meta charset="utf-8">

     <!-- Datatable CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

     <!-- jQuery Library -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Datatable JS -->
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
     <!-- Genter Based Student Count -->
    <span id="total_male_student"></span>
    <span id="total_male_student"></span>

    <table id='empTable' width='100%' border="1" style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <td>S.no</td>
                 <td>Username</td>
                 <td>Name</td>
                 <td>Email</td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
     </table>

     <!-- Script -->
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function(){

         // DataTable
        $('#empTable').DataTable({
             processing: true,
             serverSide: true,
             ajax: "{{route('getEmployees')}}",
             columns: [
                 { data: 'id' },
                 { data: 'username' },
                 { data: 'name' },
                 { data: 'email' },
             ]
         });

      });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is working perfectly, but as you can see on my aaData array I am passing two more array `$totalMaleStudent & totalFemaleStudent`, & in my html code I have two span tag to show those data how can I put the data on that span tag using same ajax request, please help me solve this issue, Thanks in advance.

I am trying to fetch the datatable data with some extra aaData array for input the data outside of the datatableif possible

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply devlin, as I mentioned I am new in programming it would be nice if you can give some example for DOM & success, I try with success but getting some error which I don't understand, hope you can help me with some example, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done & solve the issue without help..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#empTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{route('getStudents')}}",
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'username' },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'email' },
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            // Get the custom array from the aaData property.
            var customArray = this.api().ajax.json().aaData;

            // Set the values of the HTML tags.
            $('#total_male_student').html(customArray.total_male);
            $('#total_female_student').html(customArray.total_female);
            $('#total_student').html(customArray.total_student);
        }
    });
});
```